# Ember Transaction has no method add

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I'm attempting to create an ember `transaction` to commit a single model to the backend api.

Coffeescript:

```
comic = App.Comic.createRecord(title: @get('comicTitle'))
transaction = comic.get('store').transaction
transaction.add(comic)
transaction.commit()
```

Which gives the javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    return DS.Transaction.create({ store: this });
  } has no method 'add'
```

I've googled various different ways to use ember transactions, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm using the latest version of ember data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coffeescript to js translation may not be happening correctly. Try changing to

```
transaction = @get('store').transaction()
```

I have found the implicit method invocation in coffeescript trips up in Ember occasionally.